# Raspberry PI with windows 10 IOT core blink example not working

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I have Raspberry pi 3 model B and i have installed windows 10 IOT Core. I have connected LED with T Cobbler and I am trying to blink the LED. But nothing is happening. Below is my configuration which i have done which is written in C# with UWP project and also find the image of the setup

[image]

```
  public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral;
    private GpioPinValue value = GpioPinValue.High;
    private const int LED_PIN = 17;
    private GpioPin pin;
    private ThreadPoolTimer timer;

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        InitGPIO();
        timer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(Timer_Tick, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));

    }
    private void InitGPIO()
    {


        pin = GpioController.GetDefault().OpenPin(LED_PIN);
        pin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        pin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(ThreadPoolTimer timer)
    {
        value = (value == GpioPinValue.High) ? GpioPinValue.Low : GpioPinValue.High;
        pin.Write(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a hardware issue, has nothing to do with software. Look up the wiring: plus (as output from the GPIO pin) goes to the LED, then to the resistor and then to the minus bar. However, minus is not connected to the minus bar at all, so the LED is not lit. Connect the minus bar to ground to solve the problem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to hardware, not to software

Comment: Thomas is correct. Your resistor is not grounded.